# Transfer initial PostgreSQL database from development to Heroku production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I have an initial set of production data stored locally in the development database that I'd like to migrate to production for a starting point for data. What's the best way to transfer this data?

It does not seem evident if there is a way to use `pgbackups` as per the instructions.  Perhaps I have to run a manual backup of some sort locally and then push it over with `pgbackups` and if that is the case, I'd appreciate some specific instructions on accomplishing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some additional digging and an answer from Heroku, the answer for importation of initial data is to:

1) If using PGSQL locally, first dump the data:

`pg_dump -U your_username your_database_name -f backup.sql`

2) Then follow the instructions found here for importation to Heroku's database:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#importing_from_a_backup

Comment: Right.  I tried but it told me I had to wait a day. :)  Not sure why ppl have been voting my question down. LOL  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Seems strange to me as I thought it was rather clear: "I have an initial set of production data stored locally in the development database that I'd like to migrate to production for a starting point for data."  I don't know how it an be much more clear.  Oh well! :)

Answer (score 4):

First dump your local database using [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup-dump.html):

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h ... mydb > mydb.dump
```

and then use `heroku pgbackups:restore`:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore heroku-database-url url-to-your-mydb.dump-file
```

Note that the `mydb.dump` file needs to be accessible by the Heroku servers.

The Heroku Dev Center page has detailed instructions:

> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Understood, however I thought that this was "dangerous" from some of what I read.

Comment: Additionally, are you familiar with setting up of Synchronous Replication between a remote Heroku pgsql server and, for example, local servers?

Comment: @ylluminate: `db:push` might be dangerous if you already have production data but you don't have any so there's nothing to overwrite or lose. I'm not familiar with replication at Heroku.

Comment: db push is for this exact purpose. It will be fine.

Comment: I do have some production data.  It is archived data that I've collecting for some time (several million rows of data).  It's not complex and there are no foreign keys / joins involved in the particularly large table with the most complex data type being a numeric(18,12).

Comment: So I did go ahead and try this as there was nothing to lose.  I did get an error: Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2011-10-12 12:00:00.000000+5894032800"

Comment: This command syntax has changed, but the link article contains updated instructions

Comment: @JoshDiehl: Thanks for the heads up, I've updated things to better match the new way.